# Unable to Get Response from Server share Point

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

```
-(NSString *)getSoap{
    NSString *getEnvelopeData = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\n"
    "<s:Envelope xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
    "<s:Header>\n"
    "<a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://tempuri.org/IHelloWorldService/GetData</a:Action>\n"
    "<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:e2c3af4e-5d69-4fd8-94bd-0e0f00976dad</a:MessageID>\n"
    "<a:ReplyTo>\n"
    "<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>\n"
    "</a:ReplyTo>\n"
    "</s:Header>\n"
    "<s:Body>\n"
    "<GetData xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
    "<value>0</value>\n"
    "</GetData>\n"
    "</s:Body>\n"
    "</s:Envelope>\n"];
    return getEnvelopeData;
}
-(void)loadSoapRequest{


    NSString *soapMessage = [self getSoap];
    NSLog(@"soapMessage %@",soapMessage);

    NSString *urlString = @"http://l-156024038.testad.com:9000/HelloWorldService.svc";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];    
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];


    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"l-156024038.testad.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"GetData" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"Basic " forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];    
//    theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:45];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}

//At this point connection is setup and delegate is set to self, now is time to use connection delegate methods. Four methods that we gonna use:

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    NSLog(@"response Value %@",response);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"Data Received %@",webData);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Error with connection %@",error);
}
```

From The code above i am not able to get response from the server!

Its always calling didFailWithError delegate method!

Comment: @Sixten Otto Error with connection Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x6a37870 {NSErrorFailingURLKey

Comment: Some casual googling suggests the 303 error code might be a malformed HTTP request/response. I'd try removing your explicit Host and Content-Length (which the system should be able to derive) first, and then keep going until you get a response from your server (which will probably be an failure of some kind), and then see where you are.